# How to load multiple csv into pandas without concatenate?

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I would like to apply two separate graphs to each text file in a folder with subdirectories, however I wouldn't want them to be joined into one data frame.
I am currently only able to load one file into pandas at a time. If I put the root directory, I get an error that the File doesn't exist.

```
data = pd.read_csv(r'/Users/work/DexterStudio/DataFolder/*', sep=" ", header = None, na_values='NaN')

# organize data
data.drop(data.columns[[4]], axis=1, inplace=True)
data.columns = ["timestamp", "x", "y", "z"]

#get current axes object
frame1 = plt.gca()

#draw two graphs
plt.plot(data['timestamp'],data['x'],color='r', label='x-axis')
plt.plot(data['timestamp'],data['y'], color='b', label='y-axis')

# hide axes
frame1.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.show()


plt.plot(data['timestamp'],data['z'],color='g', label='z-axis')
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.show()
```

Comment: *I am currently only able to load one file into pandas at a time*...just like any other python structure (list, tuple, dictionary) or object you can load as many pandas dfs as memory allows.

Answer (score 0):

Just do two read statements into two variables and go from there:

```
data1 = pd.read_csv(r'/Users/work/DexterStudio/DataFolder/file1', sep=" ", header = None, na_values='NaN')
data2 = pd.read_csv(r'/Users/work/DexterStudio/DataFolder/file2', sep=" ", header = None, na_values='NaN')
```

Note naming the files in the read statement and that you now have data1 and data2

Comment: Do you think it would be best to implement a for loop? I have about 8 subdirectories with about 9 folders in each one with multiple txt files to apply this script to.

Comment: An entirely different question, depends on your objective and how general you want to be, and if you want to process serially in memory or all at once in memory.

Comment: If you want to loop through directories check that issue out  to read a directory then loop through file that it contains or that meets a criteria. But a different issue than this question.

Comment: Thanks! I will work on editing this to ask the proper question.